# Updating list in one class after action in another

Tags: android

I have a problem where by I have two activities, activity 1 and activity 2. Activity 1 contains a listview of contents in my SQLite database, activity 2 contains a button that when pressed preforms a query on the database. This query when run will alter the information in activity 1's list.

When I press the button the query works fine but the listview in activity 1 does not get updated. I know I have to use `notifyDataSetChanged` on the listview in order to have the list information updated.

My problem is how do I call this method on the list in activity 1 from the button listener in activity 2?

**Listview and adapter in activity 1**

```
   String[] columns = new String[] {adapter.KEY_CONTENTS_NAME, adapter.KEY_CONTENTS_MEASUREMENT, adapter.KEY_CONTENTS_UNIT};

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.ingredientName, R.id.ingredientMeasurement, R.id.ingredientUnit};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row2, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    ListView ingredientList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredientList);
    ingredientList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

**Button in activity 2**

```
Button cookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cookButton);
    cookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //simple SQL query
            //call to activity 2 to update the list
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post more code or information. What do you mean by class? Do you have different activities? How does your layout look.

Comment: @Claud25 updated the question to be more specific

Comment: @Hayes121 when the button is pressed in one activity, why do you care to change the data set of other activity which is in the background!

Comment: The button pressed deducts values from the listview, so when I deduct the values and enter the list view I want to see that the values in the list have chaged

Comment: When the user press cookButton... Do you finish the current activity?

Comment: @DavidRauca yep it closes when clicked

Comment: Did you check if your db is updated correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult` to achieve this.

In your **first** activity when you want to start the second activity like this using startActivityForResult.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
int FIRST_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100
startActivityForResult(intent, FIRST_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

In your **second** activity when doing the click you want to setResult okay and then quit the activity to return to the first activity.

```
Button cookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cookButton);
    cookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //simple SQL query
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

In your **first** activity you have to override `onActivityResult` and then update your list.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == FIRST_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
      myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

So you can communicate with activities by using onActivityResult. If you want to pass the data you got back from your SQL query in the **second** activity to your **first** activity you can use `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)`

Answer (score -1):

You could start activity using startActivityForResult. Here is the documentation and an example: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

On the first activity you should have something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
            // load data from db
            // add data to the list view (create a new adapter or clear the items from the old one and add the new items)
            // notifyDataSetChanged on adapter
        }
    }
}
```

Before calling notifyDataSetChanged. Load again info from db (and check if it was updated) and add it to the list view. Then call notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score -1):

Then write this function in your list activity:

```
@onResume
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

As you go back to that activity, this function will be called and you can notify about the changes here by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: When I try implement this I get an error saying `myCursorAdapter` cant be resolved because it is in the `onCreateMethod`